# Same login credentials on 2 wordpress installations.

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress on my main domain www.domain.com which includes simple wordpress blog and I want to install wooCommerce in my sub-domain www.subdomain.domain.com
Can I use same login credential for login into both the installations (form user point if view).
If user have logged in into the www.domain.com then there is no need to log-in again into www.subdomain.domain.com

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into WP plugins for this - this would come down to session management - actually, let me back up - are you asking if two domains can use one database or if two domains can use one single sign on? Have you tried WP Multisite? http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Comment: I guess this will help. Let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

Multsite will give you this functionality.

Check out this link - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/single-login-across-multiple-wordpress-installations